# One word for someone who eats hurriedly

Tags: single-word-requests

What do we call someone who hurriedly pounds on food and eats like as though never seen before. I would like to know an alternate word for that person, either an adjective or noun.

Comment: There are a few idioms that work for this, such a 'wolfing his food' or the less well know but descriptive 'pelicaned' from Under Milkwood.

Comment: wolfing sounds right.

Comment: Perhaps `jungli`. http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/jungli

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A [**gobbler**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gobbler) is a common way to describe a person who eats too quickly.

[**Trencherman**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/trencherman) is uncommon but might to fit the bill, though its connotation is more one of quantity than speed.

A [**binger**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/binger) is someone who eats rapidly and excessively.

A **[pig](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pig#Noun)** is someone who eats uncouthly, noisily, and or rapidly.

Comment: Ahhh, now I know why I eat my food slowly - I use Google.

Comment: @XanderLamkins Took me a second. Well done.

Answer (score 5):

I would use either **bolt** or **scoff** as in

> He bolted his food so fast he finished his starter before I had raised my fork.

From online dictionaries a description is:

> Bolt: To eat (food) hurriedly and with little chewing

Comment: Well not really.What i actually want to suggest is an adjective that can be used for, friends who (bolt) on food as soon it arrives on the table in the canteen.Does that sound right?

Comment: You should perhaps change the question then - at the moment it reads like you want the word for eating hurriedly, but you say you want the word for someone who eats hurriedly, is that right?

Comment: fascinating, in the US we call the second word "[scarfing](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=scarf%20it%20down&defid=1455582)" as in "He scarfed down his food."

Answer (score 5):

I would call them a *[glutton](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/glutton)*:

> : one given habitually to greedy and voracious eating and drinking

The adjectival form is *gluttonous*.

Comment: I normally think of _gluttony_ as referring more to the quantity of food consumed, as opposed to the pace at which it is eaten. (Still, not a bad word to add to the discussion.)

Comment: @J.R. I agree, but I felt it should make an appearance.  :)

Answer (score 4):

You could say he *gobbled up* everything on the table.  For your friend you could say he is a *gobbler*.

According to The Free Dictionary *gobbler* means:

> gobbler - a hasty eater who swallows large mouthfuls.

Answer (score 3):

Bolt may be what you are looking for:

1. The act of bolting food.

1835   J. Wilson in Blackwood's Mag. 37 133   The difference between a civilized swallow and a barbarous bolt.

http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/21143?rskey=4OhmMY&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid

Comment: Well not really.What i actually want to suggest an adjective that can be used for, friends who (bolt) on food as soon it arrives on the table in the canteen.Does that sound right?

Answer (score 2):

Also there is the term **boarding-house manners** ... presumably since when you live in a boarding house you must eat quickly before the food runs out.  And those who have lived in a boarding house at one time may retain this habit.

Answer (score 2):

The verb [*guzzle*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/guzzle) means “eat or drink greedily”, and the noun *guzzler* is derived from that. It’s commonly used in the phrase “gas guzzler” to describe a motor vehicle with poor fuel economy.

Comment: *[Guttle](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/guttle)* ("To put into the gut; to eat voraciously; to swallow greedily; to gorge, gormandize") seems to be more specific to eating than does *[guzzle](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/guzzle)* ("To drink (or, sometimes, eat) quickly, voraciously, or to excess; to gulp down; to swallow greedily, continually, or with gust").

Answer (score 1):

Tachyphagia - is the word that means to eat rapidly or fast.
You can look the word up in the Concise English Dictionary - or just search on internet

Answer (score 0):

[Gourmand](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/gourmand?s=t) comes to mind, "a person who is fond of good eating, often indiscriminatingly and to excess."

I would say that such a person "stuffs their face" which I like for vividness. I was going to suggest that you could coin "face-stuffer" -- but if you google the phrase, you'll see that others already have.

Answer (score 0):

[**Devourer**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define%20devourer) might be suitable for you.

> to swallow or eat up hungrily, voraciously, or ravenously. to consume destructively, recklessly, or wantonly

Answer (score -1):

"Chow-hound" reads like it fits what you're looking for best.  The word kind of defines itself: One who wolfs food down, like a wolf or dog. Or, to be more polite: One who eats with great gusto.  (Noun - as in, "You're such a chow-hound; wait 'til everyone is served," or "Don't be a chow-hound and pass the dish.")

Comment: A *chowhound* is someone who is always ready to and likes to eat, not necessarily someone who wolfs his food.