# Word to describe someone who makes frequent bodily sounds

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I am wondering if there is a word for someone whose bodily noises are especially loud. Example actions include:

Sample sentence:

> The world had never quite seen a body like Jared's. Between the lip smacking, farting, and labored breathing, he was the embodiment of .

-Lip smacking

-Breathing heavily

-Frequently humming/murmuring

-Flatulent

-Heft or weight to all their actions resulting in noise

Someone similar question [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73014/one-word-for-someone-who-eats-hurriedly), except this word would extend beyond eating. **The character is not dirty, so words like slovenly don't really work.**

I thought the appropriate word might be gesticulating, but that is more concerned with the behavior of how someone delivers speech.

Comment: But is there a version of noisy that relates specifically to their body?

Comment: I would call him a 'fartifier".

Comment: Gesticulating *feels* right but...there must be some word out there! +1 for Shrexy

Comment: Or perhaps "fartsical".

Comment: There are words for people who fart and burp a lot (gassy, flatulent, maybe even fartsical) but that wouldn't apply to lipsmacking, heavy breathing, or other noises like cracking joints, sniffing, sneezing, yawning, coughing, etc. I think "loud"/"loud in every way" may be as good as you can get, but I hope someone finds something.

Answer (score -1):

Not an exact answer, but an aversion to these sounds is sometimes called **misophonia**. Finally discovered a word to capture my original feeling.